# Как добавить шрифт Cramaten?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Не могу подключить даный шрифт, в фигме есть в интернете не найду

Comment: закидываете `.ttf` шрифт в каталог сайта и добавляете через `@font-face`

Comment: Дякую, вийшло)))